# Defining `lstset` parameters for multiple languages

Tags: listings

I am using the [`listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings), and have defined `lstset` parameter sets for multiple programming languages. I would like to select a parameter set when beginning a `lstlisting` or `lstinputlisting` by selecting the language corresponding to the parameter set definitions. I appreciate, however, that language selection at this stage only affects formatting of language-specific syntax and is not connected to the preamble parameter set definitions. Rather, enumerating multiple such definitions is fruitless as the last set of definitions overrides all the former ones (or so it appears). Therefore, I would like to know how to define and subsequently invoke multiple `lstset` parameter sets.

As a very rudimentary example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{language=C,frame=lines}
\lstset{language=C++,frame=none}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
 printf("Hello World");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
#include <iostream.h>
main() {
 cout << "Hello World!";
 return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

As one can see, both languages are displayed using the second defined parameter set (`frame=none`). I would like to use a key-value pair in the `\begin{lstlisting}` macro to invoke the appropriate language-specific parameter set defined in the preamble (as suggested by my use of the `language=` key-value pair). Is this possible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use multiple `\lstdefinestyle` to define your own styles, and then combine them as desired. With this approach you can incorporate previous styles and apply tweaks to them as well.

Below I have defined the styles `numbers` which specifies the settings to be used for the line numbers, and a style `MyFrame` which defines a `shadowbox` for a frame.  These two styles are used to define a `MyCStyle` and a `MyC++Style` style.  Note that in the `MyCStyle` I override the frame settings, and in the `MyC++Style`, I override the background color setting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% Copied from the listings documentation
\lstdefinestyle{numbers} {numbers=left, stepnumber=1, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=10pt}
\lstdefinestyle{MyFrame}{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},frame=shadowbox}

\lstdefinestyle{MyCStyle} {language=C,style=numbers,style=MyFrame,frame=lines}
\lstdefinestyle{MyC++Style} {language=C++,style=numbers,style=MyFrame,frame=none,backgroundcolor={}}

\lstset{language=C,frame=lines}
\lstset{language=C++,frame=none}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=MyCStyle]
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
 printf("Hello World");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=MyC++Style]
#include <iostream.h>
main() {
 cout << "Hello World!";
 return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also define your own language dependent environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{C}
  {\lstset{language=C,frame=lines}}
  {}
\lstnewenvironment{CPP}
  {\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,frame=none}}
  {}
\begin{document}

\begin{C}
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
 printf("Hello World");
}
\end{C}

\begin{CPP}
#include <iostream.h>
main() {
 cout << "Hello World!";
 return 0;
}
\end{CPP}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this be modified to accept something similar to \lstinputlisting{somefile.cpp} for larger code pieces that would make a solution like this a little less user friendly? I've got files in several syntaxes (particularly c++ and MATLAB) that I would like to be able to typeset in the same document. If there's somewhere in a manual that I've missed, I'd really appreciate a nice point in the right direction.

Comment: @DaveDoyle  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57562/lstinputlisting-does-not-include-file-within-lstnewenvironment