# lstinputlisting does not include file within lstnewenvironment?

Tags: listings, environments, input

I want to use `lstinputlisting` to include a file with code within an `lstlisting` block, which is defined through a new environment. However, the `lstinputlisting` command itself, not the code, is reproduced verbatim in the code block. MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\definecolor{customblue}{RGB}{235,241,245}

\lstnewenvironment{terminalblock}{%
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{customblue},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible}}{}

\begin{document}
 \begin{terminalblock}
  \lstinputlisting{code.cpp}
 \end{terminalblock}

\begin{verbatim}
 \verbatiminput{code.cpp}
\end{verbatim}

\begin{lstlisting}
 \lstinputlisting{code.cpp}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The same problem occurs in the standard `lstlisting` and `verbatim` environments as well. The PDF document just contains `\lstinputlisting{code.cpp}` three times, as shown.

[image: mwe.png]

Since the background of the block generated by the custom environment is the correct colour, so I think the configuration settings are working in the custom environment, but not `lstinputlistings`. I don't know if it's relevant, but these are the contents of `code.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#define abusing using

abusing namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout<<"Hello, world!"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `terminalblock` environmnet is for code directly input; it doesn't make much sense to use `\lstinputlistings` inside this environment since it will be taken verbatim (although it could be done, for example, by escaping to LaTeX). A better approach is to define a style and use this style both for your environment (to be used to input direct code) and for `\lstinputlistings` (to be used to include code from external files); also notice that you are using `frame=single`, but setting the rule width to `0pt` so no lines will be drawn.

Here's your code with the defined style and `\lstinputlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{customblue}{RGB}{235,241,245}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
  backgroundcolor=\color{customblue},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible
}

\lstnewenvironment{terminalblock}{%
  \lstset{style=mystyle}}{}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[style=mystyle]{code.cpp}
\end{document}
```

and with the `terminalblock` environment:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{customblue}{RGB}{235,241,245}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
  backgroundcolor=\color{customblue},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible
}

\lstnewenvironment{terminalblock}{%
  \lstset{style=mystyle}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{terminalblock}
#include <iostream>
#define abusing using

abusing namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout<<"Hello, world!"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
\end{terminalblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help. I always learn a great deal every time I ask a question here.