# Highlighting code like one would in a SE post

Tags: color, verbatim, highlighting, backgrounds

When posting on SE, users can "highlight" code by using the `` ` `` symbol. Is there any way to get that in LaTeX?

My intention is to highlight segments of code or particular functions. To be clear, I'm not speaking of something like [Syntax highlighting for different programming languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106538/syntax-highlighting-for-different-programming-languages). I want to be able output `this_instead` (no magic wizardry involved).

I'm not sure what this is called, so I didn't know how to search for it. I'll delete it if it's a duplicate though.

Comment: Perhaps others share my thoughts, but I'm definitely not clear on what you're after...

Comment: @Werner I think the OP would like the output from `\lstinline!this_instead!` but without typing `\lstinline!` and only typing backticks.... sounds like some category code wizardry would be needed, and a very dangerous path...

Comment: @Werner DL6ER has exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorbox{gray!25}{\texttt{this\_instead}}
```

Customize for your own needs

Comment: You ought to mention that you need `color` package for `\colorbox` and if you use the `!` color syntax you need `xcolor`

Answer (score 6):

Using Martin Scharrer's `newverbs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs,xcolor}

\newverbcommand{\severb}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}}
  {\end{lrbox}\colorbox{gray!25}{\box\verbbox}}


\begin{document}
\severb`abc_def`
\end{document}
```

Note that the save bin `\verbbox` is provided by the package.

The usage of `\severb` is identical to `\verb` (including the *-variant).

[image]